# Is "inactivate" really a word?

Tags: verbs

At my business most of the employees use the word *inactivate* frequently. Is this proper grammar? I've always used *deactivate*.

Comment: [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Inactivate%2CDeactivate%2C+inactivate%2C+deactivate&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) is also a fun (not authoritative) reference on word frequency.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are 88 examples of *inactivate* in the Corpus of Contemporary American English and 102 for *deactivate*, showing they occur with about equal frequency. Most of the examples for *inactivate*, though, are used in a biological context, talking about inactivating viruses, genes, and “potent mutagenic compounds”, for example. So *inactivate* appears to be a term of art in the science of biology.

Comment: Inactivate is also common in technology.  I believe it derives from the fact that "active" and "inactive" are two opposing states, which leads to "activating" and "inactivating".

Comment: @Lynn, it's not common in my experience (as a computer / firmware / embedded software engineer). I don't think I've ever heard anyone use it in a non-life-sciences professional context.

Comment: @cp.engr FWIW, as an application developer I do hear it frequently (e.g. when referring to account/billing states).

Answer (score 8):

According to OneLook, it is a word in 25 dictionaries:

http://www.onelook.com/?w=inactivate

- verb:  make inactive
- verb:  release from military service or remove from the active list of military service

Answer (score 1):

The New Oxford American Dictionary reports just an example of sentence with inactivate.

> inactivate ɪnˈæktəˌveɪt/
>   verb [transitive]
>   make inactive or inoperative: *household bleach does not inactivate the virus* | [as adjective] (inactivated) *an inactivated polio vaccine*.

Outside that context, I have never heard somebody using that verb.

Answer (score 1):

Another word that is used with a similar meaning is **de-** activate. But "inactivate" is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary.com says:

> in·ac·ti·vate /inˈaktəˌvāt/
>   Verb: Make inactive or inoperative: *inactivate the virus*.

And according to Google *deactivate* has 8,180,000 results; *inactivate* has 17,600,000 results, implying it is even used more.  Though there may be some specific domain in which it is used a lot on the Internet (scientific papers? military?).

Answer (score 0):

When I was in the military way back in the seventies, we frequently used "active" and "inactive", and we used the very "activate" but never "inactivate". Contemporary usage seems to derive chiefly from the computer industry ('inactivate' and 'inactivated' are frequently used in programming commentary.